# How to get clicked/selected items of a QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently looking to a way to get the name of the selected items of a `QTreeWidget`.

I have create multiple `QTreeWidgetItems` to generate a file browser-like.

I need to know how to get the name of the folder selected.

I have found the

```
this->MyTree->selectedItems();
```

to get it but I'm not able to store the feedback which is supposed to be a `QList` format.

Any examples on how to store the `selectedItems list` ?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "to store the feedback". You already have the selected items in a QList now, this is what answers your question.

Comment: What do you mean by feedback ?? selectedItems() return you list of QTreeWidgetItems through which you can access its contents and extract your data.

Comment: If I click on "filename.txt", I would like to be able to have this string in a variable I can re-use later

Answer (score 4):

From the Qt documentation: [QTreeWidget Class Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html) , [QTreeWidgetItem Class Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html)

`selectedItems()` is a function of `QTreeWidget`.

> QList QTreeWidget::selectedItems () const
>
> Returns a list of all selected non-hidden items.

`text()` is a function of `QTreeWidgetItem`

> QString QTreeWidgetItem::text ( int column ) const
>
> Returns the text in the specified column.

Define a list of `QTreeWidgetItem` to store return value of `selectedItems()` .
For each item in the list use `text()` function to get it's string.

```
QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> itemList;
itemList = this->MyTree->selectedItems();
foreach(QTreeWidgetItem *item, itemList)
{
   QString str = item->text();
   //str is what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    ...
    connect(treeWidget, &QTreeWidget::itemClicked, this, &MyForm::onItemClicked);
    connect(treeWidget, &QTreeWidget::itemActivated, this, &MyForm::onItemClicked);
}

void MyForm::onItemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int) {
    if (item == item0) {
        stackedWidget->setCurrentWidget(widget0);
    }
    else if (item == item1) {
        stackedWidget->setCurrentWidget(widget1);
    }
}
```